# Making table column data as an email address

Tags: html, email, html-table

The table is populated with Ajax from a CSV file, each row has member's  details, one column has the member's  email address.
I want to make that email address so that if I click it, it will launch my email app.
I mean, the address will become a hot link.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set, ie. onclick("function()") attribute, on the targeted cell. Once click, onclick("function()") will point to the function to launch the email app. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am NOT clear however how to do what you are telling me.